# Selected values from a table to be represented as columns by a query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have this table

```
  -visitId- | -vital-              |-value-
    43475   |   vital-pulse        |    1
    42818   |   vital-tempreture   |    37
    42818   |   vital-pulse        |    37
    43475   |   vital-tempreture   |   103
    57126   |   vital-tempreture   |    37.5
    57126   |   vital-pulse        |    5
```

All the values in the column -vital- belongs to vital-pulse and vital-temperature I want these 2 categories to be 2 columns with respective vital values against each column showing with the visit ID. I tried pivot aggregating with -visitId- column, but how to have it in final output?

Desired output as following

```
  -visitId- | -vital-tempreture-   |-vital-pulse-    |
    42818   |      37              |    37           |
    43475   |      103             |     1           |
    57126   |      37.5            |     5           |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation seems to be simple enough:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (visitid, vital, value) as
  2    (select 43475, 'vital-pulse'     , 1    from dual union all
  3     select 42818, 'vital-tempreture', 37   from dual union all
  4     select 42818, 'vital-pulse'     , 37   from dual union all
  5     select 43475, 'vital-tempreture', 103  from dual union all
  6     select 57126, 'vital-tempreture', 37.5 from dual union all
  7     select 57126, 'vital-pulse'     , 5    from dual
  8    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  select visitid,
 10    max(case when vital = 'vital-tempreture' then value end) vital_tempreture,
 11    max(case when vital = 'vital-pulse'      then value end) vital_pulse
 12  from test
 13  group by visitid
 14  order by visitid;

   VISITID VITAL_TEMPRETURE VITAL_PULSE
---------- ---------------- -----------
     42818               37          37
     43475              103           1
     57126             37,5           5

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Littefoot turns out pivot is not what I needed